# Improving Socket Performance in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I am new to Network Communication methods. I just developed a very simple server/client connection using the procedure described in the Microsoft website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx

I am using the socket to transfer large amount of data (double numbers) between a FORTRAN program (client) and a C++ program(server). (In the FORTRAN, "USE IFWIN" provides most of the windows programming functions including the ones for defining clientsocket)

I would like to improve the performance of transferring data. Do you think using any library (like boost) can improve the performance for large amount of data? What exactly is the difference between the Microsoft procedure and using libraries like boost?

Any comment is appreciated

Comment: You may be able to get a minor boost by increasing the maximum TCP window size: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938219.aspx

Comment: If the network is the problem no library can help. The main thing to do is use a very large socket receiver at the receiver and a large socket send buffer at the sender.

Comment: Try I/O Completion Ports.

Answer (score 1):

I think first you should determine if the performance of network is a problem for you application(s).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to improve bulk data throughput across the network where you control both ends of communication is to compress it. I recommend zlib for this purpose. I am not sure what APIs/bindings are available in FORTRAN, but worst case you could implement the compression yourself using any of the well known, publicly available algorithms (Huffman encoding, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

You could also try sending data in chunks. 
So by the time you have read the next chunk, you would have been able to process the previous chunk.

like this: [Chunk-size;Chunk-Data]   [Chunk-size;Chunk-Data]...

Comment: How will that help exactly?

Comment: You have two threads, Thread A reading data in chunks. Once it gets the first chunk, it notifies thread B and starts reading the next one chunk. Thread B upon notification, uses the chunk data and does something with it. Whether this idea is feasible or not depends on whether thread B can use the chunks to do some operation to get performance gain.

Here is an article on similar concept for http connections http://sharovatov.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/http-chunked-encoding/

Comment: The thing that makes this fast, if anything, is the two threads, not the chunks. TCP is a streaming protocol but under the hood it works in chunks anyway. There are some very substantial chunks already provided in the socket send and receive buffers. Your citation is about HTTP chunking, which solves the very specific issue of having to send the content-length ahead of the data when you don't know the entry of the data.